# Wix installed app (and shortcut) shows admin symbol

Tags: installation, wix, icons, admin

After successfully creating and testing an application I've also manually created the installer for this app using Wix instead the ClickOnce provided by VS.

Anyway, the installation is successful, places all the registry keys in correct locations, same for files where they need to be, and the shortcuts (and all is cleaned up afterwards).

The issue is not critical, I'm just really picky :D
On the main exe file that the Wix setup is installing, and on the shortcuts that points to this, they have the little blue and yellow admin shield on the bottom right of the icons. The application does not require admin permissions to work properly, nor does the application actually bring up the UAC or run as admin anyway (unless explicitly done through right-click > Run as admin).

The question is how do I prevent the shield from being applied to the application and shortcut icons?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi"
     xmlns:netfx="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/NetFxExtension">
    <?include "Macros.wxi" ?>

    <!-- Installation Settings -->
    <Product Id="*"
             Name="$(var.NameApp)"
             Language="1033"
             Version="1.0.0.0"
             Manufacturer="$(var.NameCompany)"
             UpgradeCode="$(var.GUID_Upgrade)">
        <Package InstallerVersion="200"
                 Compressed="yes"
                 InstallScope="perMachine"
                 Comments="Windows Installer Package"/>
        <Media Id="1"
               Cabinet="product.cab"
               EmbedCab="yes"/>
        <MajorUpgrade DowngradeErrorMessage="A newer version of this software is already installed" />

        <!-- .NET Framework Check -->
        <PropertyRef Id="NETFRAMEWORK40CLIENT" />
        <Condition Message="This application requires .NET Framework 4.0. Please install the .NET Framework then try again">
            <![CDATA[Installed OR NETFRAMEWORK40CLIENT]]>
        </Condition>

        <!-- Installation files, folders, reg-keys, shortcuts, etc -->
        <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
            <!-- Program Files Folder -->
            <Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder">
                <!-- Company Application Folder -->
                <Directory Id="INSTALLDIR" Name="$(var.NameCompany)">
                    <!-- Main Application Files -->
                    <Component Id="CmpAppMain" Guid="$(var.GUID_CmpAppMain)">
                        <File Id="FileAppMainEXE" Source="$(var.PathExe)" Vital="yes" />
                        <RegistryKey Root="HKLM"
                                     Key="SOFTWARE\$(var.NameCompany)\$(var.NameApp)">
                            <RegistryValue Name="installed"
                                           Type="integer"
                                           Value="1"
                                           KeyPath="yes" />
                        </RegistryKey>
                    </Component>

                    <!-- Common DLLs for multiple apps -->
                    <Component Id="CmpAppLibs" Guid="$(var.GUID_CmpAppLibs)">
                        <File Id="FileDeviceDLL" Source="$(var.PathLibDevice)" Vital="yes" />
                        <File Id="FileUtilDLL" Source="$(var.PathLibUtil)" Vital="yes"/>
                        <RemoveFile Id="FileClrDevice" Directory="INSTALLDIR" Name="Comms.log" On="uninstall"/>

                        <RegistryKey Root="HKLM"
                                     Key="SOFTWARE\$(var.NameCompany)">
                            <RegistryValue Name="Lib Path"
                                           Type="string"
                                           Value="[INSTALLDIR]" />
                            <RegistryValue Name="Lib Ver"
                                           Type="string"
                                           Value="1.0.0"
                                           KeyPath="yes" />
                        </RegistryKey>
                    </Component>

                    <!-- Common Resource Files -->
                    <Directory Id="FolderResource" Name="rsc">
                        <Component Id="CmpAppRsc" Guid="$(var.GUID_CmpAppRscs)">
                            <File Id="RscOilDb" Source="$(var.PathRscOil)" Vital="no" KeyPath="yes"/>
                        </Component>
                    </Directory>

                </Directory>
                <!-- END - Company Application Folder -->
            </Directory>
            <!-- END - Program Files Folder -->

            <!-- Start Menu Folder -->
            <Directory Id="ProgramMenuFolder">
                <!-- Start Menu Company Folder -->
                <Directory Id="ProgramMenuCompany" Name="$(var.NameCompany)">
                    <Component Id="CmpLnks" Guid="$(var.GUID_CmpLnks)">
                        <Shortcut Id="LnkStartMenu" 
                                  Name="$(var.NameApp)"
                                  Description="$(var.NameApp)"
                                  Target="[INSTALLDIR]$(var.NameExe)"
                                  WorkingDirectory="INSTALLDIR">
                            <Icon Id="IconApp" SourceFile="$(var.PathRscIco)" />
                        </Shortcut>
                        <RegistryKey Root="HKCU"
                                     Key="SOFTWARE\$(var.NameCompany)">
                            <RegistryValue Name="Lnk"
                                           Type="integer"
                                           Value="1"
                                           KeyPath="yes" />
                        </RegistryKey>
                        <RemoveFolder Id="RemoveStartLnk" Directory="ProgramMenuCompany" On="uninstall" />
                    </Component>
                </Directory>
                <!-- END - Start Menu Company Folder -->
            </Directory>
            <!-- END - Start Menu Programs Folder -->
        </Directory>
        <!-- END - TARTGETDIR -->

        <Feature Id="FeatCore" Title="Core Application Files" Level="1">
            <ComponentRef Id="CmpAppMain" />
            <ComponentRef Id="CmpAppLibs" />
            <ComponentRef Id="CmpAppRsc" />
        </Feature>
        <Feature Id="FeatLnks" Title="Start Menu Shortcut" Level="1">
            <ComponentRef Id="CmpLnks" />
        </Feature>
    </Product>
</Wix>
```

Comment: Does the app have a manifest at all? I'm wondering if it's got a highestavailable or asInvoker setting that means that it might sometimes elevate, and I'm assuming from what you said that it doesn't have a requiresAdministrator setting there.

Comment: I believe the app does have an auto generated manifest from visual studio, but is currently not included within the installation package. Should I try including this with the install? And if so is there perhaps anything that may need altering within it before hand too?

Comment: A manifest is nearly always embedded in the exe itself, that's what needs verifying. I'm guessing that the exe is being built with an embedded manifest. No need to include it in the install.

Comment: Right, I'll try and take a look into manifest files and what visual studio generates before commenting further, if you have any additional ideas that may also be the cause though it may be worth investigating while I'm at it?

Comment: Sorry about not replying for a while. A little correction in what I may have said or forgot to say earlier, it turns out that you do need admin permissions to even run the application. What's more is that I've tried changing the msi build so that everything installs to "AppDataFolder\Company" instead of "ProgramFilesFolder\Company" and I still need admin to install and run the application.
Also I can't see any manifest files generated, if they are, they are temporary by VS, and I have no idea where to correct the installer so that the program (not the installer) doesn't need admin to run.

Comment: That being said this issue is now very important (I previously mentioned "not critical" in OP). For some reason my development PC I do not get prompted for admin confirmation (even on guest account) but on other computers this is required.
This is not suitable for what is required and I'm really hoping not to have to resort to ClickOnce as this will not easily allow the integration of other future products into the same directories for shared libraries and resources.

Comment: Yet more information on the issue. I have tried installing on a different Win7 machine and the app still shows admin, but also doesn't prompt UAC on admin or regular accounts (just like on my build Win7 PC).
Also I tried building (both the app itself and msi) on the second Win7 PC to see if anything was different on a freshly installed VSC13 but the output msi still behaves in the same manor. I'm also going to test the installer no WinXP to see how that works (if that works) and post more results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Does the app have a manifest at all? I'm wondering if it's got a
>   highestavailable or asInvoker setting that means that it might
>   sometimes elevate, and I'm assuming from what you said that it doesn't
>   have a requiresAdministrator setting there.
>
> A manifest is nearly always embedded in the exe itself, that's what
>   needs verifying. I'm guessing that the exe is being built with an
>   embedded manifest. No need to include it in the install.

Thanks for the info. The issue was with the manifest which wasn't being generated in the first place due to ClickOnce settings, and then once I've generated or made my own manifest for the project it's also not being embedded into the executable.

ClickOnce publishing places it within the installation directory with the installer it generates for you. Because I didn't want to use click once (and I assumed after reading about the manifest it would be embedded in exe) my app didn't have a manifest...

The only thing I'm curious about now is why the default behavior is to ask for admin rights (I thought that would be the worst thing to do by default).

Anyway... Thanks for the help